# Why is the aggregated paint time less than individual frames

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, paint

I have taken a paint timeline trace with Google Dev Tools, the results of which are shown below.

From the screenshot the aggregated paint time for the selected period is 4.169ms.
However as can be seem from the bar graph at the top, each frame has approx 16ms of paint - as shown by the green bars.

So, how can the aggregated time for 12 frames with approx 16ms paint each (192ms) be just 4ms aggregated?

[image]